# Saving a nested JSON response of what I'm able to call a print function on?

Tags: python, json, api, export-to-csv

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to save the results of an API call to a CSV. When I run the print function below, it prints *exactly* what I want saved. I've tried dictwriter, I've tried jsondumps, there's always something wrong with the output (putting everything on one row + doing columns too, or adding writing like t,h,i,s to the end of each entry).

```
    fList = sys.argv[1]
with open(fList, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as ins:
    for line in ins:
        targetDomain = line
        url1 = "https://websitehere={0}".format(
            targetDomain)
        response = requests.get(url1).json()
        for subs in response["result"]["records"]:
            with open('output.csv', 'a', newline="") as f:
                print(subs)`
```

The code above prints:

```
{'domain': '***redacted out of caution***', 'firstSeen': 1629178483, 'lastSeen': 1629178507}
{'domain': '***redacted out of caution***', 'firstSeen': 1631174847, 'lastSeen': 1631174878}
{'domain': '***redacted out of caution***', 'firstSeen': 1630654337, 'lastSeen': 1630654337}
{'domain': '***redacted out of caution***', 'firstSeen': 1630465072, 'lastSeen': 1630465072}
```

Which is exactly what I want saved in a CSV but cannot for the life of me figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: why do you have an image of the code result? it would have been easier to copy paste the result with the `domain` values replaced, rather than attaching an image with the values scratched out.

Comment: @rv.kvetch  good point, just frazzled. I fixed it.

Comment: That output  isn't a CSV format.  It is more [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format.  Please clarify.

Comment: `print(subs,file=f)` would send your print output to the file.  That may be all you need. I'd drop the `newline=''` though.  That's a `csv` module requirement.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Right, I got to that by navigating down to `for subs in response["result"]["records"]`

Comment: Right..what?  Do you want a CSV or a JSON lines format? A CSV would be `domain,firstSeen,lastSeen` followed by `redacted,1629178483,1629178507`, etc.  Your output and terminology don't match.  Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm sorry, I'm trying but I'm still new to programming. I'm trying to find a way to save the same data I get when I use print(subs) on the code above. I technically just need the domain.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I figured it out based on your earlier suggestion. `with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
                print(json.dumps(subs), file=f)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for this. Example with `DictWriter` (taken from the docs):

```py
import csv

rows = [
    {'domain': 'xx', 'firstSeen': 1629178483, 'lastSeen': 1629178507},
    {'domain': 'xx', 'firstSeen': 1631174847, 'lastSeen': 1631174878}
]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=list(rows[0].keys()))

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - Thank you.

```
with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
                print(json.dumps(subs), file=f)
```